# Unix using grep with if

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

This my code

```
if [[ (grep -x $idle | grep -x $dead | grep -x $busy) || grep -x $idle1 | grep -x $dead | grep -x $busy1 ]] ./Event.log 
then 
    echo "Events are running Successfully" >> ./Event.log 
else 
    echo "One or more Events are down. Check the log and restart the Events." >> ./Event.log
fi
```

I'm getting the error

```
0403-057 Syntax error at line 14 : `-x' is not expected.
```

What's up?

Comment: Are you hoping that `grep -x $idle` is going to be reading from `./Event.log`?  What do you want `grep -x $idle1` to read from?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? I can't guess; the different pieces of your code don't fit together in any way that makes sense to me.

Comment: Unless `$idle` and `$dead` contain exacty the same string, `grep -x $idle | grep -x $dead` will never return a match.

Comment: @tripleee: they could be regexes, in which case it is a reasonable way of finding the conjuction of the two. But you're probably right that it is an error.

Comment: With `-x`, the entire input line must match. The output from the code mentions different "events" (in a way which suggests they are actually services or similar) so it seems highly unlikely that you need three different regexes to find one of them.

Comment: @WilliamPursell grep -x $idle and grep -x $idle1 are two different variables which is read from the same ./Event.log file. Below is my script

idle="IDLE:       1"
dead="DEAD:       0"
busy="BUSY:       0"
busy1="BUSY:       1"
idle1="IDLE:       0"


if [[ (grep -x $idle | grep -x $dead | grep -x $busy) || grep -x $idle1 | grep -x $dead | grep -x $busy1 ]] ./Event.log
 then 
 echo "Events are running Successfully" >> ./Event.log
 else 
 echo "One or more Events are down. Check the log and restart the Events." >> ./Event.log
fi

Comment: You cannot pass an input file to grep on the outside of `[[]]`.  That is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 5):

In bash, [`[[`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) is syntactically a *command* which is terminated with the matching `]]`. It is not part of the syntax of the `if` command, whose syntax starts:
    `if commands ; then`

If you want to test whether a *command*  succeeded or not, you just do that:

```
if grep -q pattern file; then
  # grep found pattern in file
else
  # grep did not find pattern in file
fi
```

Within a `[[` command, bash expects to find a conditional expression, *not* another command. That's why `grep -x ...` is a syntax error. `-x` is a unary operator in a conditional expression, which is true if its argument is the name of an executable file, but in that expression it is being used as though it were a binary operator.

If you wish to test for more than one pattern with `grep`, you can use the `-e` option to specify each option; the grep will succeed (or select) lines matching any of the options:

```
if grep -q -e pattern1 -e pattern2 file; then
  # grep found pattern1 or pattern2 in file
else
  # grep did not find either pattern in file
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

By a long shot, I am guessing that you want `Event.log` to contain one each of either member of the pairs.  This could be done with something like

```
if awk "/^($idle|$idle1)$/ { ++idle; next }
        /^($dead|$dead1)$/ { ++dead; next }
        /^($busy|$busy1)$/ { ++busy; next }
        idle && dead && busy { exit 0 }
        END { exit 1 }' Event.log; then
    echo Yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

This collects three variables; if all of them are true, the Awk script exits with a success exit code (that's zero); otherwise, it will return failure (any nonzero value).

It would make more sense to print the result from Awk, too, but there is an awful amount of assumptions and guesswork in this answer already.